# Tracking SQL Server tables using Change Tracking; but how can I be notified of when a table is modified?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to migrate data from SQL Server to an external warehouse (PostgresSQL) continuously (pretty much a read replica).

For this, I am using [SQL Server's Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

> After change tracking is configured for a table, any DML statement that affects rows in the table will cause change tracking information for each modified row to be recorded. To query for the rows that have changed and to obtain information about the changes, you can use change tracking functions.

My question is: how can I make SQL Server alert me that there is a change, so my application can query for the changes?

Is there any way I can create a trigger for that and make it publish an event?

Thanks.

Comment: No, SQL Server does not publish events like this. I'm not sure any database does, other than basic triggers. That's not really what cdc is for. Think "audit" instead of event, and instead use application logic to poll and publish events.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hi, thanks a bunch. When you said "That's not really what cdc is for", I assume you're meaning it doesn't "publish events", but it is still useful for my use case, correct? Do you think that an application querying for changes every 1 min or so, is the way to go here? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you're really trying to do. But it sounds more like you want a service layer in front of the database, where applications can't use the DB directly, but instead must talk to the service. Then, in the service layer, you can have your code to also publish events at the time you make changes.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That's the best case scenario but unfortunately we're unable to access the application that makes changes to the DB... so yeah the only way is to pull changes from within the DB itself. Why, do you think that's a terrible idea?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn [`SqlDependency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) does this, and it's built in to the standard SqlClient library

Comment: Yes, the other option is to poll for changes periodically. Given the right indexes, it's not a bad option

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the help. I am using Haskell so `SqlDependency` is not an option, unfortunately. Why would I need indexes if I am using the Change Tracking feature? Or they use that internally? Thanks.

Comment: No, I think Change Tracking internal tables are already indexed